# Content security on the cloud/ hosted web

Tags: cloud-storage

I have purchased space (web hosting) with a provider. I would like to manage (edit, add, delete etc.) my content entirely on the cloud  content (without download/upload). This will be done by a couple of staffers. What must I do if I would like them:-

1. To be able to access the content only through the web host - all edits must be done on the host and they may not download or upload or email etc. any of the content
2. They may have access only to specific content on the host and not to all

Comment: You can do this by installing a [Content Management System (CMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). But, which of the many CMS is appropriate for you and how to install it is off-topic here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  I do use a CMS which is installed on my hosting server. However, there is nothing preventing people from copying the content locally, emailing it externally, downloading/uploading from the local machine etc. I am looking for ways to prevent all of this.

Comment: If your system is configured so that the CMS can be bypassed or if the CMS is configured to be too open then you have to add the appropriate restrictions or change the CMS if such restrictions are not possible. But - your question provides no useful information about the current setup and is very broad. Basically you are asking "I've bought a car. I have never driven any car but can somebody explain me quickly how to drive this (not specified) car?".

Comment: You can prevent them from being downloaded directly (htaccess, etc) - and only have an interface be able to alter it.  But that depends on the type of content of course; text works quite well (although they can copy paste content), images, not so much.